# Excel not displaying unicode characters

Tags: vba, excel, unicode, utf-16

I've tried to print the Unicode characters (UTF-16) using the following code:

```
Sub PrintUnicode()
For Each Cell In Range("A1:J6553") '2^16/10: displays 10 chars in each line
Cell.Value = ChrW(i)
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Sample output:

[image]

So the actual character id if you will is: `10*(RowNumber-1) + ColumnNumber`

After browsing the spreadsheet downwards, I started noticing empty rows. Playing around with these rows, I noticed some of cells looked empty and other cells had invisible values that were only visible when you double clicked on the cell.

I filtered them out:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Please take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character You can test it using Cell.Value = `"a" & ChrW(i)` in your code, but be careful, it may last long.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about combining chars. Can you post that answer ? I want to give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look here: [Combining character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) You can test it using:

```
Cell.Value = "a" & ChrW(i)
```